# Does "do" fully inherit the grammar of the verb it refers to?

Tags: verbs, do-support

To avoid confusion with this question, here is an example

> We consider Nigeria a developing country as we **do** Angola.

So, is that grammatical? Should I put a preposition? Can I instead say **do it with**?

P.S. I do understand that there are less clumsy ways to say the sentence. But that's not in my field of interest right now.

Comment: This is a very nice question. +1 from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original sentence is perfectly grammatical.  If I understand you correctly, yes, the part of the sentence after *as* does inherit the grammar of the first part.  I think part of what might be tripping you up is [the many different uses of *as*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as) and the different structures we use for the different meanings.

In this case, there's no place for **it** because there's nothing for "it" to refer to, except Nigeria and that doesn't make any sense.  *We consider Nigeria a developing country as we do Nigeria with Angola?*  You would use "as it" if the sentence was something like "The situation is in Nigeria **as it** is in Angola" because then there is something for *it* to refer to: the situation.

Similarly, there's no place for **with** because the usage is "**We consider** Nigeria (or Angola)", not "we consider *with* Nigeria (or Angola)" - and the structures need to be parallel in both parts, which means if the first half has no preposition, the second half should have no preposition either.  *With* would be appropriate if the verb in the first half was something like *negotiate*:  "We negotiate **with** Nigeria as we do **with** Angola."

Answer (score 2):

## The grammar

Your sentence uses an [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)). The "underlying sentence" is:

> - We consider Nigeria a developing country as we consider Angola a developing country.

Grammatically, *do* is considered a [pro-verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-verb) in your original example, since it **"stands in" for the verb or [verb phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_phrase)** (like a pronoun "stands in" for a noun). The verb phrase "consider ___ a developing country" is what was swallowed up as part of the ellipsis.

### Can we use "with"?

No, it should be more obvious now, looking at the underlying sentence, that it wouldn't make sense grammatically to add *with*:

> - We consider Nigeria a developing country as we (do) <s>with</s> [consider] Angola [a developing country].
> - We consider Nigeria a developing country as we (do) [consider] <s>with</s> Angola [a developing country].

### Awkwardness

I think your example sounds awkward, but it's hard to pinpoint why.

It might have something to do with the fact that *as* usually allows [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion#Other_cases), but that doesn't work in your sentence.

It's also not clear to me what you meant with *as*. It doesn't sound like a comparison should.

---

You might want to look at some real world examples, like these ones from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support):

> - They swam, but I didn't.
> - He looks smart, and so do you.
> - You fell asleep, and I did, too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer:) On the awkwardness: yeah, as I said in the description, the example is not that brilliant, since I was more concerned with the grammar rather than good looks.

Answer (score 1):

I would say in most cases yes, "do" does inherit all the meanings of the verb, at least with this particular grammar.  An example:

> Sue eats dinner precisely at 7pm, as do I.

Both of us eat dinner at 7pm, exactly.  Another example:

> The searching algorithm employs a recursive bubble sort, as does the queuing algorithm.

It doesn't matter if you understand what a "recursive bubble sort" is -- you know that both the searching algorithm and the queuing algorithm employ it.